# Best Versioning System for R

Tags: version-control, r

I have a plethora of both short and long pieces of R code that I would like to track as they evolve.

Does anyone have any recommendation or experience using version-control software with R?

Comment: it's not a big deal, but are you platform dependent? win? linux?

Comment: Nothing special about R as fa as version control is concerned. This question is equivalent to "What is the best version control system?" which has been asked and answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77485/what-are-the-relative-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-git-mercurial-and-bazaar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138621/best-version-control-for-lone-developer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326429/what-version-control-system-is-most-trivial-to-set-up-and-use-for-toy-projects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224396/should-i-look-at-version-control-systems-beyond-subversion

Comment: I'm not locked to one OS, I use a mixture of win, osx, and nix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

- whatever your colleagues, friends, ... use --- most systems are technically equivalent and you want to *foster* rather than *hinder* collaboration
- whatever is supported in the editor or IDE you use most

so as ever so often it comes down to network effects --- popular choices create more users which creates more support in tools etc.

R itself does not care. Source code is just text.  Personally, I like SVN a lot and use it at home, at work, at R-Forge, on Google Code, on Sourceforge, ...  R Core also uses SVN but as I said, it does not *really* matter.  Your choice, your headaches when you need to admin or fix things.

Comment: Dirk, GREAT points! It's easy to overlook the importance of a social network to support tools (the Internet may be minimizing this, but only on the margin).

Comment: Agreed, the social element is huge. At this point I'm not working with anyone else on the code but it's quite possible in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Subversion or Git would be my recommendations.  I don't think the effectiveness of the versioning system depends on the source code you put in it.  R shouldn't be any different from Java or C# that way.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing unique about R that would drive a version control system decision.  There are many R projects hosted on [Github](http://github.com/) (in Git) and on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) (in Mercurial or Subversion).  R-Forge (http://r-forge.r-project.org/) uses SVN.

You may want to have a look [at this question for some views on the modern source controlsystems: Git, Mercurial, and Bazaar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77485/what-are-the-relative-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-git-mercurial-and-bazaar).

Assuming that you will use either Git, Mercurial, or SVN, I would suggest having a look at [Github](http://github.com/).  It has many very nice features for collaboration.

Comment: I'd love to be able to use github/google, but unfortunately a few of the statistical models are proprietary.

Answer (score 2):

[Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org) is wonderfully easy to set up and quickly start using. It also includes a web interface, issue tracker and a wiki, all built-in to the single executable. Fossil is the version control system for SQLite (written by the same author) and runs on Mac, Win and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use and strongly suggest Eclipse with the [StatET plugin](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) combined with [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org) for subversioning.