# What VCS to use?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, tfs

At the company I work we are starting a project, and starting from scratch since me and 2 other developers are the first devs of the company, we are trying to establish a base for our work.

Because we are going to develop to Windows Phone and Android and possibly iPhone in the future . We will be using Visual Studio 2010 and IntelliJ for WP and Android respectively (from what we can see not much to chose here, any advice is welcome).

Where we can't decide yet is the VCS to use, while all of us have used SVN a lot, only 2 of us have used TFS version control, and we didn't like it much, specially having to checkout for edit and getting conflicts even if one of us does not change the file. Git and mercurial we just played with it a little.

Can anyone provide some insight on what are the main advantages between these, and help us chose?

- We want something with a simple merge process (tfs seems to lose here).
- That can be used easily (if possible) with IDEs we are using (as far as we know tfs and svn are supported on both, not sure about others).
- Easy tagging and branching.
- Central repository easy to maintain (since git and mercurial are distributed)
- Cost is not a problem.

Thanks

Comment: I'd just stick with Svn, since you guys know it and like it..  It's a great product!

Comment: If you guys are using Windows for development, and for ease of learning, I'd learn toward using Mercurial. You can still have central repositories in Mercurial (notice stuff like http://www.bitbucket.org which offers hosting using Mercurial/Git). Mercurial has 'cheap' branching, and offers the ability to do local commits before pushing them up to a master repo. I use svn heavily too, but I miss hg/git features like local commits, fast branching (maybe this is different in SVN 1.7?), and painless merging, which I find I run into a lot in svn.

Comment: @birryree: you are asking for Gitsters to fight back with that ;) ... they've got staging and soooo many more things, too. For all practical purposes I consider Git and Mercurial equivalent and consider mostly the tool support.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED - I actually use and love Git and the git staging area, and all the other cool default stuff like `git bisect` (hg has an equivalent). I recommended Mercurial because this sounds like a Windows-only shop, and Git on Windows is inferior to Git in *nix, whereas Mercurial is fine everywhere. I might be wrong, I last used msysgit maybe...8 months ago?

Comment: @birryree: I'm more of a Mercurial aficionado (because I work across Windows and unixoid systems), but yeah it is a point I was making too in my answer :)

Comment: "Have you come for the five minute or the fifteen minute argument?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I look at version control systems beyond Subversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224396/should-i-look-at-version-control-systems-beyond-subversion)

Answer (score 4):

A matter of taste. It's as simple as that.

Git, Hg and Bzr are virtually equivalent for 95% of the features and probably most of the features that most users will ever want. Still, they use different semantics for branching.

All DVCS are superior with merging.

Git tool support - to my taste - is very inferior on Windows, but on par with the other two on all other systems.

Central repository is a convention in all of them, not a must.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you explain why you say "All DVCS are superior with merging"?  A few examples would be great.

Comment: Basically it's about "merge tracking", which Subversion only introduced with v 1.5. Due to their design all DVCS seem to make use of that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

With TFS 11, already out in beta as "Go Live" (means you can use it in production) you have a new kind of workspace called "local workspace" which I think you will like.

You don't have to check-out to edit files, changes are monitored in background (whether it's coming from VS or another soft or shell), then you "reconciliate" things at check-in time. Another benefit is you don't need to be connected to the TFS Server to contribute, the awful online/offline mode doesn't exists anymore in such case.

For the merging 'issue' you mention, throw away the merge tool used by Visual Studio and go for KDiff3 or Beyond Compare, setting them up using three way merge will get you the best result. Once you know the basics trick the merging process with TFS is one of the best. Visual Studio 11 also has a brand new comp/diff tool, worth to check out.

DVCS are mostly better for Open Source projects because it enables you to create branches as you like. I don't really agree with the previous comment regarding merge being better. A merge is always painful, be sure to be in a scenario where you can benefit of three way merge (the most efficient way to reduce conflicts).

Maybe you can give a try to the TFSPreview.com platform, it's really great.

Comment: So you think merging in Git/Hg/Bzr is _not_ less painful than in CVS or early SVN? ... interesting :) ... oh well.

Comment: No, I was comparing merging with TFS to DVCS tools.

Comment: ah, well that I cannot comment. I don't know TFS well enough.